# unresolved reference error for callable in another Kotlin file

Tags: file, class, kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin (came from Python) and I'm trying to recreate a tic-tac-toe game.

I'm trying to use a class from another file but i just get this error when i compile the main file:

```
main.kt:2:21: error: unresolved reference: TicTacToeBoard
    var tabuleiro = TicTacToeBoard()
                    ^
```

In the directory, called "tictactoe", i have the "main.kt" and "board.kt" files:

The "main.kt" file:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var tabuleiro = TicTacToeBoard()
}
```

The "board.kt" file:

```
class TicTacToeBoard
```

[image: directory with two files and error]

The same happens with functions from another file.

I've seen a lot of articles and videos where this same syntax work.
What am i missing? why is this not working? and how can i use classes from another file on the main file?

**EDIT 1:** *(more information)*

I'm using VSCODE and running the file with the [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension on default settings.

kotlin information: `Kotlin version 1.6.21-release-334 (JRE 18.0.1.1+2-6)`

Comment: Your files should declare a package at the top, but I think it should work even without a package. Everything you've described sounds fine. You might try using Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: To re-affirm Ten 4's comment, your code is all fine. Are the two files next to each other in the directory structure ?

Can you post the error you are getting ?

Comment: @PaulNUK, I just added a screenshot of the error and directory with the 2 files next to each other

Comment: What are you using to build the jar file? I suspect the TicTacToe class isn't within the jar. You can just rename the jar to be a zip file and open it up to have a look. I highly recommend using Intellij and Gradle to build your Kotlin projects. Intellij will take you through a wizard to create everything for you. Make sure you pick the Kotlin DSL option when creating the build file too, unless you want to learn Groovy too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and has no problems. Kotlin auto import functions and classes from files on the same directory (not like python, where you need to manually import stuff).

The problem is how are you running the code. You are compiling main.kt without compiling all the files it needs.
In this case, you need to compile the board.kt first, then compile the main.kt, and then run the jar file.
Ex:

```
$ kotlinc board.kt, main.kt -include-runtime -d main.jar
$ java -jar main.jar
```

.

In case your project grows and it becomes unfeasible to write the name of all the files in the correct order, you can (and should) compile all the files at the same time.

Ex. using the "*" wildcard character:

```
$ kotlinc *.kt -include-runtime -d main.jar
```

Ex. in case the "*" does not work, you can use just a dot ".":

```
$ kotlinc . -include-runtime -d main.jar
```

Then you run the java file as usual.

.

Since you are using the CodeRunner to run the code, you should edit its configuration file to compile all files at once.

STEP 1:
Go to the extension page on the extension market and click the gear, then "extension configuration"
[image: extension page]

STEP 2:
Search for "executor map", then, "edit json"
[image: extension configuration]

STEP 3:
On the json file, look for "kotlin" and edit the "$filename" to the dot or asterisk (whatever work for you)
[image: edit defaut code runner]

STEP 4:
Save the file and you're good to go